# How do I get Location Services to prompt after terminating the app more than twice

Tags: ios, core-location

I have a navigation app which calls the instance methods of a`CLLocationManager` instance to prompt the user to turn on Location Services. When I run the app for the first time I select to not turn on Location Services and close the app. I then open the app a second time and the prompt appears a second time. I choose for the second time to not turn on Location Services and close the app again. When I open the app for a third time I am not prompted again to turn on Location Services. How can I force iOS to keep prompting to turn on Location Services after re-opening the app more than two times? Do I need to somehow remove the `CLLocatioManager` instance from memory in the `applicationWillterminate(_)` delegate method?

```
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

    locationManager = nil

}
```

Comment: I'm surprised you see a 2nd prompt. Normally once a user makes a choice, no prompt is ever shown again without deleting and reinstalling the app.

Comment: Yes, I am presented with the prompt exactly twice. Is there no way of somehow telling Location Services that I want to instantiate a new instance of `CLLocationManager` with no previous history of prompts displayed?

Comment: No. That's not how it works. The best you can do is send the user to your app's Settings page so the user can change their original choice.

Comment: OK @rmaddy I see, thanks. So iOS has then been designed to only prompt the user twice to turn on Location Services?

Comment: Not twice, once. It sounds like you might be terminating the app quickly enough that the permissions decline isn't recorded. (Yet, maybe?) You're either hitting some kind of race condition or just an OS bug.

Comment: I have included code which calls the instance method `locationServicesEnabled()` and reports false before I close the app, so the decline must be recorded before I close the app